# What is the standard operating temperature for the transmission in a 2012 Ford f150 4-wheel drive

Tags: transmission

I'm trying to find out what the operating temperature for the transmission is on a 2012 Ford f150 4-wheel drive pickup

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual the F150 (2009 -> Now) has the 6R80 transmission. With that transmission you should have a temp range of 193°F-215°F at normal conditions.